# Modify values before inserting through an EntityDataSource Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following EntityDataSource object:

```
 <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server"
    ContextTypeName="IntraNET_Prototype.IntraNetEntities" 
    ConnectionString="name=IntraNetEntities" 
    DefaultContainerName="IntraNetEntities" 
    EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" 
    EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="EmployeeList" 
    OnInserting="EntityDataSource_Inserting" />
```

I'm trying to add new data which I added in my gridpanel to my database.

The Problem is when I click the add button in my gridpanel I automatically get a negative value for my primarykey which is simply an id.

Therefore I'm trying to manipulate the id value from the object which will be inserted by calling the OnInserting="EntityDataSource_Inserting" method.

```
        protected void EntityDataSource_Inserting(object sender, EntityDataSourceChangingEventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

My plan was to make a new Dataset Object Reference and set that to the object which will be inserted and then modify the primarykey id here.

Anyway, my attempt to set `myDatasetObject newElement = e.Entity` did not work as VisualStudio tells me that I'm missing a cast.

How to do that correctly and set that in a right order?

Any Help will be appreciated.

If you know any better way to set the primarykey (just a continuous figure) (id marker) automatically, let me know!

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I figured out how to do what I wanted to do, I'm not sure if this is the non plus ultra way to do it, but it WORKS!

```
        protected void EntityDataSource_Inserting(object sender, EntityDataSourceChangingEventArgs e)
{
myDatasetObject newElement = e.Entity as myDatasetObject;
newElement.id = NextPrimaryID();
}
```

The ID of the element will be changed as I needed to have it and afterwards it will be saved to the database :-)

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using and what is the datatype of your PK?  You could just make the PK and identity column and then EF will take care of returning the PK value you for you once the record has been created.